# New Windows 7 installation - No Internet Connection

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I just reinstalled the whole laptop after wrapping my whole disk out. However, I am unable to work on certain functions right now. This includes widened screen, no function keys and most importantly no network detected.

Is there any reason causing this? Please tell me if it is a repeated question.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSZZi.png]

This is a link I tried to find my drivers. Unfortunately all of those related to Wifi or internet didn't work. My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad Z570.

http://support.lenovo.com/us/zh/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-z-series-laptops/ideapad-z570?beta=false

Comment: This is definitely a driver issue. Install the appropriate drivers from `Networking: LAN (Ethernet)` and `Networking: Wireless LAN` then restart your computer.

Comment: Indeed it is solved by installing drivers of the types you suggested. Thank you Michael.

Comment: Great! I added an answer, feel free to marked it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a driver issue. You will need to install the correct driver sets from the [vendor's website](http://support.lenovo.com/us/zh/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-z-series-laptops/ideapad-z570?beta=false).

Install these drivers, make sure you download the version appropriate to your OS:

- Networking: LAN (Ethernet)
- Networking: Wireless LAN

Once installed, restart and your computer will install and initialise the network hardware correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my HP laptop after my HDD crashed and had to do nee Windows 7 install. You have to reinstall the wireless and LAN drivers for your machine. Once those are installed then you can start updating windows and that should help correct the other issues you mentioned like display issues. Also there will be other drivers you need to install from the manufacturer as well. For me I had access to another PC so I downloaded the drivers on it to a USB stick and installed them to laptop via USB. Also make sure you reboot after installing the network drivers to be sure that they will work correctly and verify that you did in fact download and install the latest version and correct drivers required. My HP had 3 different sets of network drivers all for the different types of hardware versions so make sure you have the right ones. The first set I installed didn't do anything for me because they didn't match the hardware in my machine.

Hope this helps